# Derivative of $\sec^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm struggling with problem below which I eagerly want to solve. Let me know from where this problem is, if possible (the origin source of textbook). your answers might really helpful to get through the struggles with which I confront.

Question

One way of defining $\sec^{-1}(x)$ that is sometimes used is to say that $y=\sec^{-1}(x)$ $\iff$ $\sec(y)=x$ and $y \in (0,\pi]$ (alternatively, y is between 0 and pi and is the same 0 and pi, y not 0)

show that, with this definition. $\frac{d}{dx}\sec^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Comment: you should change the "differential geometry" tag and replace it with calculus.

Because: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry

Comment: do you want a hint or an answer? A hint would be to consider $\frac{dx}{dy}$

Comment: You could also try implicit differentiation. This would amount o the same thing as @Hayeder's comment. Also you can always differentiate $x=f(y)$ with out restrictions on the domain of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Please revise your title to reflect the content of your question.

Comment: More Generally, if $f^{-1}(x)=g(x)$, then,$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$$. and can you prove it?

Comment: I'm really appriciated. also I'm learning from all of you. following your advices, I'm now working on this problem. but I still wanna know the whole structure of the formal and exhaustive proof process. is there Anyone who's gonna lead me further?

Comment: eg., the precise domain, and sort of things.

Answer (score 3):

$y = \sec^{-1} x \implies x = \sec y \implies \frac{dx}{dy} = \tan y \sec y = \sec y\sqrt{\sec^{2}y - 1} = x\sqrt{ x^2 - 1}$...

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sec^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of $\sec (x)$, we can use the derivate of inverse function rule (look here [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)).

I assume $x>1$, then:
$( \sec^{-1}(x))'=\frac{1}{\sec'(\sec^{-1}(x))}=\frac{1}{\sec(\sec^{-1}(x))\tan(\sec^{-1}(x))}=\frac{1}{x\tan(\sec^{-1}(x))}=\frac{1}{x \sqrt {\sec ^2(\sec^{-1}(x))-1}}=\frac{1}{x \sqrt {x^2-1}}$.

I used these facts: $\sec^{-1}(\sec(x)))=x, \tan(x)=\pm\sqrt {\sec ^2(x)-1}$ and $\sec'(x)=\sec(x)\tan(x)$.
I have not been extremely careful about the absolute value, but I think you can make it more formal.

Answer (score 1):

We already know:

$$\sec \left(\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)=x$$

We want to take a derivative from both sides of this with respect to $x$(obviously the right hand side will give 1). To take the derivative I will use the [Chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sec \left(\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{d\sec \left(\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)}{d\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)}\frac{d\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)}{dx}=1$$

---

We already know how to calculate the derivative $\frac{d\sec{y}}{dy}$:

$$\frac{d\sec{y}}{dy}=\frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{\cos{y}}=\frac{\sin{y}}{\cos^2{y}}=\sin{y}\sec^2{y}$$

---

Let's use this in our derivative(note $\frac{d\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)}{dx}$ is what we are looking for):

$$\frac{d\sec \left(\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)}{d\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)}=\sin\left(\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)\sec^2\left( \sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)=x^2\sin\left(\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)$$

Now, how are we supposed to calculate $\sin\left(\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)$? I usually draw a triangle for these type of trigonometry identities.

[image]
Looking at the image we figure out: $\sin\left(\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$

---

Now putting everything back into our first equation, we find out:

$$x \sqrt{x^2-1}\frac{d\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)}{dx}=1 \\
\Rightarrow \frac{d\sec^{-1}\left(x\right)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}}$$